# how to fetch a block in regular expression conditionally

Tags: python, regex

Suppose i have following block in regex

```
Username: apple
email:apple@gmail.com
password:*****
userid:12
address:123HA

Username:ball
email:cat@gmail.com
password:*****
userid:123
address:8223

Username:hello
email:hello@gmail.com
password:*****
userid:12
address:12 jan
```

I want to fetch a block from the above data where **userid:12**
How can i achieve this using regex.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `[i for i in s.split('\n\n') if 'userid:12\n' in i]` where `s` is your original string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach, using `re.findall`:

```py
inp = """Username: apple
email:apple@gmail.com
password:*****
userid:12
address:123HA

Username:ball
email:cat@gmail.com
password:*****
userid:123
address:8223

Username:hello
email:hello@gmail.com
password:*****
userid:12
address:12 jan"""

matches = re.findall(r'\bUsername:(?:(?!\bUsername:).)*\buserid:12\s+\baddress:.*?(?=\r?\n|$)', inp, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['Username: apple\nemail:apple@gmail.com\npassword:*****\nuserid:12\naddress:123HA',
 'Username:hello\nemail:hello@gmail.com\npassword:*****\nuserid:12\naddress:12 jan']
```

This regex pattern says to:

```regex
\bUsername:            match 'Username:'
(?:(?!\bUsername:).)*  then match any content provided that we DON'T cross the
                       next Username: line of the following block
\buserid:12            match target 'userid:12'
\s+                    one or more whitespace characters (e.g. \n, or \r\n)
\baddress:.*?          match 'address:' followed by any content until reaching
(?=\r?\n|$)            the next CR?LF or the end of the input
```